# Поиск по экрану с подгружаемым списком

Tags: java, ios, appium

В процессе автоматизации столкнулся с местом в приложении, где есть подгружаемый список. Когда Аппиум ищет элементы, он доходит до конца списка и генерирует событие на подгрузку очередной порции данных в список. Так как полный список достаточно большой, эти операции приводят к зависанию приложения.

В логах сервера наблюдаю:

> [debug] [WebDriverAgent] Device: Dec  7 11:32:33 iPhone XCTRunner[252] : Enqueue Failure: UI Testing Failure - Failure getting snapshot Error Domain=XCTestManagerErrorDomain Code=9 "Error getting main window -25204" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error getting main window -25204}  0 1

Эта надпись появляется с некоторой частотой и приложение не отвечает ни скрипту, ни пальцам.

Как-то можно обойти эту вечную подгрузку элементов?

Окружение: appium 1.6.1, Xcode 8.1, Java 1.8, iOS 9.3

Comment: если сам список не особо важен, можно мокнуть ответ от сервера и вернуть явно короткий список.